# The meaning of "$ms$" where $m\in \mathbb Z$ and $s\in R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm trying to solve the following exercise:

Let $R$ be a ring without identity. Let $T$ be the set $R \times \mathbb{Z}$. Define addition as $(r,m) + (s,n) = (r+s, m+n)$ and multiplication as $(r,m)(s,n) = (rs + ms + nr, mn)$. Prove that $T$ is a ring with identity.

The way I've tried solving this is by first setting $(r,m)(s,n) = (r,m)$. With $n=1$ this gives $mn = m$ so then we have $(r,m)(s,1) = (rs+ms+r, m)$.

Next I was thinking of putting $s = 0_R$, i.e. the zero-element in $R$ (which exists since $R$ is a ring). The thing that confuses me is the meaning of e.g. $ms = m0_R$, since we are multiplying $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ with the element $s = 0_R \in R$. We know that multiplication by $0_R$ and an element from $R$ gives the product $0_R$, but what about the multiplication of an element in $R$ with an element in $\mathbb{Z}$? And if this isn't the way to go about, does anyone have an advice on how to solve it instead?

Comment: Normally one defines $m\cdot 0=0$ or more generally for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ you have $m\cdot n=\underbrace{m+m+\dotso +m}_{\text{$n$ times}}$, when $n\geq 0$. Similar when $n<0$ where you swap $+$ by $-$.

Comment: So even if $m$ is an element of a different group than $\mathbb{Z}$, we typically define $mn = m+m+...m$ ($n$ times) with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$? And the same when we e.g. have $0_R m$ with $0_R \in R$ and $m \in \mathbb{Z}$?

I'm surprised this hasn't been stated in the book considering how rigorous it is everywhere else. But it sure would make me happy if that's the case. :)

Comment: I think part of this exercise is to figure that out yourself. Which book do you use? Maybe the author takes this for granted, as it is common to do so, and the reader might be familiar with this "construction". Maybe from modules or even group actions.

Comment: Abstract Algebra - An Introduction, by Hungerford. Great book otherwise. And of course the thought occured to me that this would be the way multiplication between rings would work, but seing as it is so rigorous with its definitions everywhere else, it just made me a bit unsure. 

Thank you for your help!

Comment: More generally, you can extend any ring $R$ which is also an $S$ bimodule, where $S$ takes the place of $\mathbb Z$. In the defined multiplication $rs+ms+rn$, the first multiplication uses the operation in $R$, the second two use the bimodule action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $mr$ in your multiplication definition must be understood as
$$ mr = \begin{cases} \underbrace{r+\cdots+r}_{m\text{ times}} & \text{if }m>0 \\
0_R & \text{if }m=0 \\
-((-m)r) = \underbrace{(-r)+\cdots+(-r)}_{|m|\text{ times}} & \text{if }m<0 \end{cases}$$

This is the standard "scalar multiplication" used to make any abelian group into a $\mathbb Z$-module (in which case the module axioms imply that it is the *only* multiplication that works correctly), and apparently your book considers it to be either known or obvious ...